# getting multiple rows group by column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have sql table of this structure,

```
id  |  type   | name 
1   | type1  | name1
2   | type1  | name2
3   | type2  | name3
4   | type2  | name4
```

I want to get all the names grouped by the type like this

```
"type1" : [name1,name2]
"type2" : [name3,name4]
```

I am using Laravel eloquent, I tried keyBy('type') but it gives only one row of each type.
How can get all the names of one type?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT   type, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(name), ']')
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: yes exactly, i replaced it with array_agg() because I am using postgresql, but getting error in laravel , Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "array_agg(original_name)" does not exist

Comment: @Programmer The question is tagged with [tag:mysql] for some reason. WRT laravel, I'd try adding an alias

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to solve this problem.
I had the same problem, and solved it using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop:

```
$data = DB::connection('myConn')
    ->table('myTable')
    ->get()->toArray();
    
$res = [];
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    if (!isset($res[$entry->type])) {
        $res[$entry->type] = [];
    }
    array_push($res[$entry->type], $entry->name);
}
```